# Error (Access is denied) for mysql-connection-java-3.0.15-ga-bin.jar

Tags: android, database, android-studio

I'm trying to access an online database and I keep getting this error with regards to the mysql-connector-java file:

```
  Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.
    > java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\onlinedatabase2\libs\mysql-connector-java-3.0.15-ga-bin.jar (Access is denied)
```

Any ideas what to do? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried dragging the `jar` file inside your Projects folder and referencing it again?

Comment: Yeah I tried but it gave the same error